# is there a way to get service method name on a retrofit call?

Tags: java, retrofit

I am using retrofit to execute http calls:

```
this.createService().getXXX()
```

Is there a way (interceptor/adapter) to get the method name of the calling service that was called?

Comment: so you want to get the name of the service in java, i am little confused?

Comment: the called method, in this example 'getXXX'

Comment: oh so when you call the service, you want a convenient way to get the last method name that execute the request?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

> Well the easiest and most fluent approach would be to use java reflections and the storage capability of shared preferences. Alright lets say you are about to call a `refrofit` request , example a Post Request, what you would do, is to use reflection on the class to get the name, `ClassName.class.getSimpleName();` plus the `method name of interest` then get current time stamp, store this pair of information in a shared preference. If when you read from the shared preference then you that any value retrieved will be the last request sent coupled with the time. Just overwrite the key store every time you make a request this way you can conveniently track your request and time of flight. Unfortunately there is no convenient method for your request you of to forge something yourself.

Comment: But you can build a interceptor to log your request, this interceptor will only show the route though.

Comment: did you try this way?